# Contract Verification Issue

Tags: nft, erc-721

[image: i have tried to change compiler version in all source files but it is still not getting compiled optimization is enabled and I have flattened the contract as well]

i have tried to change compiler version in all source files but it is still not getting compiled optimization is enabled and I have flattened the contract as well

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract EYES is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
using Strings for uint256;

```
string public baseURI;
string public baseExtension = ".json";
uint256 public cost = 0.01 ether;
uint256 public presaleCost = 0.02 ether;
uint256 public maxSupply = 36;
uint256 public maxMintAmount = 2;
bool public paused = false;
mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
mapping(address => bool) public presaleWallets;

constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    mint(msg.sender, 2);
}

// internal
function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
}

// public
function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if (whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
            if (presaleWallets[msg.sender] != true) {
                //general public
                require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
            } else {
                //presale
                require(msg.value >= presaleCost * _mintAmount);
            }
        }
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
        _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
}

function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
{
    uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
    for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
        tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
}

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
{
    require(
        _exists(tokenId),
        "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return
        bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
            ? string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    currentBaseURI,
                    tokenId.toString(),
                    baseExtension
                )
            )
            : "";
}

//only owner
function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
    cost = _newCost;
}

function setPresaleCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
    presaleCost = _newCost;
}

function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
    maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
}

function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _newBaseURI;
}

function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
}

function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
}

function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = true;
}

function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = false;
}

function addPresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    presaleWallets[_user] = true;
}

function add100PresaleUsers(address[100] memory _users) public onlyOwner {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        presaleWallets[_users[i]] = true;
    }
}

function removePresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    presaleWallets[_user] = false;
}

function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
        value: address(this).balance
    }("");
    require(success);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check your contract using the Truffle plugin truffle-plugin-verify.
Install the plugin using this command

```
npm install -D truffle-plugin-verify
```

When it is installed, you should add the following to your truffle-config.js file to enable the plugin with truffle:

```
module.exports = {
  /* ... others configurations truffle-config */

  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

After you have compiled the contract on the network, for example on the Ropsten network, you can use the command

```
truffle run verify EYES --network ropsten
```

You can also pass the address of the contract you are deploying to the network using the command.

```
truffle run verify EYES@0x000000000000 --network ropsten
```

I believe the truffle check makes it much easier and avoids any kind of error.

Comment: how do i do this on remix?